# Css bootstrap glyphicon-calendar not showing the calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```
i need to create datetimepicker using bootstrap in my php code i write


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the scripts part i write the following

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

the datetimepicker is showing normally but when i click it the calender is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Wrap

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

inside label tag:

```
 <label class="input-group-addon" for="dateField">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </label>
```

Correction as follows:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class='col-sm-6'>
           <div class="form-group">
               <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input id="dateField" type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <label class="input-group-addon" for="dateField">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </label>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```